# windows 8.1 updates broke wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, auto-updates

Windows auto-update has killed my wifi. Its a new machine and I forgot to turn auto-update off. I've had this machine for a month and everything has been A-OK. The last updates, 13/5/2015, killed wifi and now my connection is reported as "limited".

I ran the troubleshooter -> ip config invalid.
I've done the adapter update -> best driver already installed.
I tried to manually select, in case M$ had replaced it, but there was only one entry.
The roll back option was disabled.
After googling I tried disabling auto tune, but that didnt work.

Any ideas, other than destroying M$ for making the world a terrible place?

Adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
Driver provider: Intel
Driver date: 21/7/2014
Driver version: 17.1.0.19

**EDIT:**
Tried latest driver from Dell -> no luck.
Tried latest driver from intel (17.16.0.4) -> no luck
Tried TCP/IP stack reset and got...

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Resetting Global, OK!
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting Unicast Address, OK!
Resetting Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Path, OK!
Resetting Route, OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Resetting , OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.
```

**EDIT:**
Followed TD.512's reg edit and stack reset now works.

**EDIT:**
Don't know if anything else helped but last thing I checked was the channel. They weren't aligned. Now adapter/router have same value and it works ;(

Comment: Can you put up the driver date you currently have installed?

Comment: Driver details added

Comment: Try the drivers here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24863

Comment: Those are for Windows 6.2, not 6.3

Comment: I have to write more than 15... "Eh?" @TD.512

Comment: Oh, oops, sorry... I use Kernel builds, not names and sometimes forget to switch back. Windows 6.2 is Windows 8; Windows 6.3 is 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe after 4 hours of googling, trying driver updates, random `netsh` commands, adapter tweaks, umpteen computer restarts and router restarts the thing that seems to have fixed it is setting the channel.

I checked the channel on my router, it was '6', and the one in my adapters setting (Ad Hoc Channel 802.11b/g) and it was set to '1'. When I changed it to '6' it worked.

Only 2 scenarios I can think of are...

1. Windows updates changed the channel
2. Windows updates were incompatible with old driver, driver update fixed problem but changed the channel

Answer (score 1):

I had that adapter in my old laptop. There is only one solution that I can think of, or rather, only one solution that actually worked for me.

The only thing you can do is right click on Wi-Fi, and select `Troubleshoot Problems`. Hopefully, Windows will find the break in  the adapter, and reset it for you.

The other thing you can try is doing an TCP/IP Stack reset

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- Click “Command” prompt (Admin mode)
- Type ‘netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt’
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Reboot the computer

If it says failed, open `regedit` and look for this key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a00-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\26`

Right click on the key called `26`, choose `Permissions`, add a checkmark on "Full control" for the everyone group, then rinse and repeat from <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, I missed that off the list of things I tried. I've now included that in my question.

Comment: Well, are you at liberty to refresh or reset windows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You mean reboot or system restore?

Comment: if you hold shift and hit restart from the metro menu, you will be kicked into advanced startup options, when there, you can fully reset windows, and it will take everything back to defaults. OR, you can choose to reset the software and leave all your files in place. <-- is called a refresh

Comment: Erm, not sure I want to go that far... yet! Tried the stack reset and got a failed message, i'll add it to the question.

Comment: ok, reboot and try the TCP/IP reset again

Comment: Restarted and tried again. 4th line says failed, but not what failed.
interface, ok. Neighbor, ok.Path, ok. <blank>, failed. Acess is denied.

Comment: updated again, that should hopefully work

Comment: Thanks, the reset worked without failure. Restarted, still had problem, ran troubleshooter, still getting invalid ip config.

Comment: do a printscreen of the output of `ipconfig` from CMD

Comment: http://imgur.com/kDA5IKo   ps. thanks for your time.

Comment: There! 169.x.x.x FOUND IT, you're going to have to statically assign your device an IP. it should be something along the lines of: 192.168.1.19X that you can use, or 192.168.0.19X.

Comment: Why should I do that? Anyway, I already tried but it didn't work and this is a laptop that I move around. Surely that won't help when I'm roaming? I'll just do a system restore and turn off windows-auto-fuckups :)

Comment: remove the profanity, and do a refresh, it'll work better

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing this driver directly from Intel:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24656/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Windows-8-1- which is the recommended driver for your operating system and WLAN card. (There are newer versions available but most of the time the newest drivers cause more problems than the older ones).

If that doesn't work do a system restore prior to windows update:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration worked for me:

1. Go to `Device manager`
2. Expand `Network adapters` and double click on your wireless adapter
3. Select `Advanced`
4. `U-APSD=disabled` - `Transmit power=highest` - `Preferred band=Prefer 2.4GHz band` - `Roaming Aggressiveness=1.Lowest`